# LaTeX "Could not start the command "

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have a problem with compiling a latex file.
The error that I'm getting is:
Could not start the command.

```
 pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

I looked into the forum (like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107110/pdflatex-in-texmaker-doesn-t-work-could-not-start-the-command)) but couldn't find the solution.
Using Texmaker 4.5 now and my settings look like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0P2c.jpg)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue in Windows 10. I had installed Texmaker (version 5.0.2) first and then MiKTeX. I am not sure if OP did the same. Here is what worked for me:

1. I uninstalled both Texmaker and MikTeX
2. I installed [MiKTeX](https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex)
3. I installed [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html)

Got help from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267933/66686)

**Bottom line**: MiKTex should be installed before Texmaker

Answer (score 0):

I think your LaTex path is not specified. Look in your MikTeX path for a latex file:

`"C:/Program Files/MikTex 2.9/miktex/bin" latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

and

`"C:/Program Files/MikTex 2.9/miktex/bin" pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`